# Why is the Zeeman effect an example of explicit symmetry breakdown?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, symmetry, symmetry-breaking

On [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Explicit_symmetry_breaking) they say the Zeeman effect is an example of explicit symmetry breakdown, but I don't see how. Can anyone give some hints?

Answer (score 4):

More generally any magnetic field is an example of explicit symmetry breaking, the symmetry at hand being time reversal symmetry.

Imagine a Newtonian universe with no electromagnetism (maybe some Newtonian gravity, spring forces, etc). If you tape what is going on and you would now look at your camera and play it back in reverse, every process still obeys Newton's equations of motion. We say this system is time reversal symmetric.

Now imagine an empty universe with a homogeneous magnetic field and a positron moving through it. We see the positron curving consistent with the right-hand rule. Imagine taping all of this and now playing it back in reverse. In this rewinding version, the positron will in fact violate the right-hand rule. (Go through it in your head to convince yourself.) So we say a magnetic field breaks time reversal symmetry.

Equivalently, physicists usually prefer to use the convention that the magnetic field reverses upon reversing time. Within that convention, the right-hand rule is obeyed in all cases, but now we explicitly see that the magnetic field is not invariant under the reversal of time, so we are led to the same conclusion.

Comment: So the idea of explicit break of symmetry is related to some sort of artificial break? Would you then agree to call it an artificial symmetry breaking?

Comment: By 'explicit' physicists mean: 'put in by hand'. I.e. the symmetry is broken at the level of the Hamiltonian. I suspect this is the same as what you mean by 'artificial'. This is contrasted with spontaneous symmetry breaking, where the Hamiltonian has the symmetry but the physical ground state does not.